Agregar la clase con la animación en scroll vertical
Necesitaría poder aplicar la clase cuando se vea al menos el 50%-75% del TimelineContent:
'use client'

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Timeline from '@mui/lab/Timeline';
import TimelineSeparator from '@mui/lab/TimelineSeparator';
import TimelineConnector from '@mui/lab/TimelineConnector';
import TimelineContent from '@mui/lab/TimelineContent';
import TimelineOppositeContent from '@mui/lab/TimelineOppositeContent';
import TimelineDot from '@mui/lab/TimelineDot';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { FaCaretDown, FaUserNinja } from 'react-icons/fa6';
import { useMediaQuery } from '@mui/material';
import TimelineItem, { timelineItemClasses } from '@mui/lab/TimelineItem';
import { myCareerConfig } from '@/config/my-career/my-career.config';
import Accordion from '@mui/material/Accordion';
import AccordionDetails from '@mui/material/AccordionDetails';
import AccordionSummary from '@mui/material/AccordionSummary';



const MyCareerPage = () => {

  const isMobile = useMediaQuery('(max-width:600px)');
  const myCareer = myCareerConfig;

  const [slideIn, setSlideIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setSlideIn(true);
    }, 100);
  }, []);

  return (
    <section className='w-full h-auto lg:h-auto lg:min-h-screen py-20 md:p-20'>

      <Timeline position='alternate'>

        {/* Escondido */}
        <TimelineItem className='hidden'>
          <TimelineOppositeContent>
            <FaUserNinja size={30} />
          </TimelineOppositeContent>
        </TimelineItem>
        {/* Escondido */}

        {
          myCareer.map((value, index) => (
            <TimelineItem key={index}>
              <TimelineOppositeContent
                className='mx-0 my-auto text-[#441006] dark:text-[#d2e4ff]'
                variant="body2"
              >
                {value.dateRange}
              </TimelineOppositeContent>

              <TimelineSeparator>
                <TimelineConnector className='bg-[#ed4709] dark:bg-[#e2b5fd]' />
                <TimelineDot className='bg-[#ed4709] dark:bg-[#e2b5fd] dark:text-[#030637]'>
                  <value.dotIcon size={30} />
                </TimelineDot>
                <TimelineConnector className='bg-[#ed4709] dark:bg-[#e2b5fd]' />
              </TimelineSeparator>

              <TimelineContent
                className={`py-3 px-4 flex flex-col items-center gap-3 rounded bg-[#44100625] dark:bg-[#d2e4ff25] ${slideIn ? (index % 2 == 0 ? 'slide-in-right' : 'slide-in-left') : ''}`}>
                <Typography variant="h6" component="span" className='text-[#ed4709] dark:text-[#e2b5fd] text-3xl'>
                  {value.empress}
                </Typography>

                <div className='h-60 w-full relative overflow-hidden'>
                  <img src={value.empressImage} loading='lazy' className='w-full h-auto absolute top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 object-cover' />
                </div>

                <p className='self-start text-[#441006] dark:text-[#d2e4ff] text-pretty text-justify'>
                  {value.description}
                </p>

                {
                  value.progression && (
                    value.progression.map((prog, indexProg) => (
                      <Accordion key={indexProg} className='w-full bg-transparent'>
                        <AccordionSummary
                          expandIcon={<FaCaretDown />}
                          aria-controls="panel1-content"
                          id={indexProg.toString()}
                        >
                          <Typography className='text-[#ed4709] dark:text-[#e2b5fd]'>{prog.promotionDate.toLocaleDateString()}</Typography>
                        </AccordionSummary>
                        <AccordionDetails>
                          <Typography className='text-[#441006] dark:text-[#d2e4ff]'>
                            <span className='font-extrabold text-[#441006] dark:text-[#d2e4ff]'>Evaluación:</span> {prog.evaluation}
                          </Typography>
                          <Typography className='text-[#441006] dark:text-[#d2e4ff]'>
                            <span className='font-extrabold text-[#441006] dark:text-[#d2e4ff]'>Nuevo puesto:</span> {prog.position}
                          </Typography>
                        </AccordionDetails>
                      </Accordion>
                    ))
                  )
                }

              </TimelineContent>
            </TimelineItem>
          ))
        }

      </Timeline>

    </section >
  )
}

export default MyCareerPage

Hay que contar con que son objetos iterados que van a ir yendo en scroll vertical. Por tanto, los primeros 2 se ven el 100%, esos aplicarían de manera directa la clase y entrarían uno por la izquierda y otro por la derecha.
A partir de ahí, a medida que se vaya haciendo scroll down necesito una forma de poder aplicar la clase cuando se viera el 50-75% del elemento.
Gracias de antemano.
